# Map values to column in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables. Table A has details of Customer and Order and Table B has details of Order and values and I want my final result with combination of all the details. As order date is common field in both the columns and we have duplicate order date values mapped to order id, how can I achieve that in plsql?

Table A

```
CustomerID OrderID OrderDt
---------- ------- ------
123        76542   01APR
123        77923   01APR
123        78542   02APR
456        77654   02APR
789        76890   03APR
```

Table B

```
OrderDt OrderValue
------- ----------
01APR   760
01APR   540
02APR   154
02APR   228
03APR   990
```

Final Result

```
CustomerID OrderID OrderDt OrderVal
---------- ------- ------- --------
123        76542   01APR   760
123        77923   01APR   540
123        78542   02APR   154
456        77654   02APR   228
789        76890   03APR   990
```

Comment: Why do you need pl/sql?  This is just SQL.  Do you know about JOINS?  If not, read up on that.  Also, storing dates as strings is a bad idea. What date do you store for 01/01/2022 and 01/01/2023?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this and guarantee the correct result. Your `Table B` needs a foreign key referencing `Table A` OrderID. You shouldn't try to fix a broken data model with a SQL hack.

But if you want to try anyway...

```
with taba as (
  select a.*
         ,row_number() over (partition by a.orderdt order by a.orderid) as rn
  from a)
 , tabb as (
  select b.*
         ,row_number() over (partition by b.orderdt order by b.orderval) as rn
  from b)
select  taba.customerid
       ,taba.orderid
       ,taba.orderdt
       ,tabb.orderval
from taba
join tabb
  on  taba.orderdt = tabb.orderdt
  and taba.rn      = tabb.rn
/
```

This guarantees a **consistent** result set, but not necessarily a correct one, because part of the join criteria is determined by sorting on `orderval`, which is clearly nonsense. As I said, we can't fix a broken data model with SQL.

Now if your table B has some other column which you haven't included in this example and that column implies a creation order for records then by all means use that column in the `tabb` subquery `row_number()` ordering clause.

But the only correct solution is to **add ORDERID to table B**.

---

On the topic of broken data models, the comment from @oldprogrammer is spot on: `orderdt` should be defined with a DATE datatype rather than as a string. There are many reasons for this:

1. Your string does not include a year element so your data will be corrupted after 365 days of usage.
2. You will not be able to sort records in calendar order: `01APR` sorts before `01JAN`, `01AUG` sorts before `02APR`, and so on.
3. You can't use date arithmetic to easily answer questions such as, *'which customers have made more than one order in the last seven days?'*
4. You don't have a the guarantee of strong data-typing, so the column could contain any string values.
5. It's industry standard practice to use DATE or TIMESTAMP datatypes to store dates and timestamps. Conformance with such practices is always the best idea.